# Why does this test yield True

Tags: matrix, pattern-matching, numerical-value

I have this test implemented in my code, when I import a numeric matrix, which I thought would be bulletproof, but it's failing in this case:

```
In[]:= MatrixQ[{{}, {}}, NumericQ[#] && MatchQ[#, _Real] &]

Out[]= True
```

I don't get it.

Answer (score 6):

Because there are no elements in your matrix.
So there is no element which is not numeric and real.

```
MatrixQ[{{}, {}}, False &]
```

returns `True` too.

So you have to exclude that case:

```
MatrixQ[##, NumericQ[#] && MatchQ[#, _Real] &] && !MatrixQ[##, False &] &
```

Comment: I'd find the example `MatrixQ[{{}, {}}, False &]` somewhat more convincing.  (Typo? If not, consider `MatrixQ[{{1}, {1}}, True]`.)  Or maybe `MatrixQ[{{}, {}}, Print]` vs. `MatrixQ[{{1}, {1}}, Print]`. In any case, +1.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Whoops. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: Thanks! And how can I catch this case? I have tried several things without success.